# Set a range in moment.js

Tags: javascript, momentjs

I would like to know how to set a day range on moment.js, I just need to show just the weekdays not the weekends.

At the moment I'm using this:

```
Database: moment().subtract('days', 1).toDate(),

{{Database}}
```

I use this to show the database refresh but on weekends there are no updates.

Comment: How were you planning on using the code you have included? Please provide more explanation of what you are trying to do. At the moment your question is unclear.

Comment: I just pick up the date today but this is showing weekends saturday and sunday but I don't need to show these ones.

Comment: Sorry but it's still not at all clear what you're asking. You need to explain exactly what you want to do, giving full details of the context. At the moment you are assuming that we know a lot more than we do. The code you have included is completely ambiguous.

Comment: but with moment its simple this code I'm getting the date of moment everyday and subtract one day, so I'm showing with handlebars the Database so today will show 10/02/2014, I just don't want to show days of saturday and sunday.

Comment: I understand what the code does, that's not the problem. The problem is that you haven't made it clear what you are trying to do with it. Maybe you're trying to get the previous entry from the database, which will normally be from yesterday but will be from last Friday if the current day is a Monday? Please edit your question to add more detail.

Comment: you complicate this, it's just show the day but not show weekends and finish.

Comment: I was just guessing at what you might be trying to do and trying to show an example of how you could explain it more clearly. So you want to get the previous day but not include the weekends?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on your comments, I think that this does what you want:

```
m.subtract(m.day() === 1 ? 3 : 1, 'days');
```

If `m` is a `moment`, this will subtract 1 day except for on Monday (where `m.day() === 1`) where it will subtract 3 days. This means that `m` will go through the days backwards like Wednesday, Tuesday, Monday, Friday, Thursday, etc.

If this is what you want, I am happy to help you modify your question to make it more clear. If not, please edit it to explain what you are trying to do.